# Entity Framework 4 Query Interceptors without ADO.NET Data Services

Tags: .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

We are using entity framework 4 to access our database. Every table has got some security related fields which we would like to check on every query (e.g. start/end date, level of security, element active or not).

Is it possible to define something like a global query interceptor that adds additional checks for the security fields? I know that query interceptors exist for WCF Data Services, but we do not use data services.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunatelly no. `QueryInterceptor` is feature related to WCF Data Services and whole implementation related to its usage is internal so you can't reuse it elsewhere without using WCF Data services.

Basically `QueryInterceptor` is just condition added to executed query so you can in the same way wrap your data access to the class which will expose method like:

```
public IQueryable<TEntity> GetQuery() where TEntity : IOwnedByUser
{
    return GetObjectSet<TEntity>().Where(e => e.Owner == CurrentUser.Login);
}
```